Do NextJs serverless functions shutdown the whole node js process when return?
I have such an api route in my nextjs application:
import {NextResponse} from "next/server"
import {getToken} from "next-auth/jwt"
import prisma from "@/libs/prisma"
import Joi from "joi"
import {Role} from "@prisma/client"
import makeApiRequest from "@/libs/makeApiRequest"
const validationSchema = Joi.object({
    proofId: Joi.number().integer().min(0).required(),
    userId: Joi.number().integer().min(0).required(),
    content: Joi.string().max(1000).required()
})
export async function POST(req) {
    try {
        const [input, session] = await Promise.all(
            [req.json(), getToken({req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET})]
        )
        const {error, value} = validationSchema.validate(input)
        if(error) return NextResponse.json({error: error.details[0].message}, {status: 400})
        const proof = await prisma.proof.findFirst({
            where: {id: value.proofId},
            include: {order: true}
        })
        if(!proof) return NextResponse.json({error: "There's no proof with the specified id"}, {status: 400})
        if(
            !session ||
                session.id != proof.order.userId &&
                session.role != Role.Admin &&
                session.role != Role.Designer &&
                session.role != Role.Manager
        ) return NextResponse.json({error: "Not authorized for action"}, {status: 401})
        const proofMessage = await prisma.proofMessage.create({data: value, include: {user: true}})
        makeApiRequest(
            `${req.nextUrl.origin}/api/sendProofMessage`,
            {apiKey: process.env.SERVERLESS_API_KEY, id: proofMessage.id}
        )
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50))
        return NextResponse.json({proofMessage})
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(`${e.message}\n${e.stack}`)
        return NextResponse.json({error: "Internal server error"}, {status: 500})
    }
}

The problem is I thought I could ask one of my serverless functions to send an email to the recipient while I'm returning the message that has been created in the database to the user. But it looks like I return and NextJs shuts down the whole process of that function, thus makeApiRequest (which is just returns a Promise of fetch() but with a good error handling) doesn't have time to even send a request to another serverless function. If I put 50ms sleep after the makeApiRequest(), the email is sent (I tested it), but if I don't, then I can see in the logs that there's no request to the /api/sendProofMessage. Is that an okay solution, and if it's not, what's the alternative?

If makeApiRequest returns a Promise, can't you simply await it?

Yes, I can await it. And I did until I noticed that email service is really slow. It takes 15sec to return a message to the client. Without await it's only ~500ms.

As far as I understand it, serverless will spawn a container on request and shut it down on return so you have a problem there. I guess that the slow service is called from /api/sendProofMessage and you await it there.
The issue, if you don't await in the "main" api route, is that the shutdown occurs before the service is called so I suggest that you add the await in your main route and remove it from sendProofMessage

Wow, I didn't think about this. I'll try it and return!

Hm, I think if I don't wait for the email service to complete its task in the sendProofMessage, it would shutdown there too, cause it is also a serverless function.

It would be a perfect solution to wait only for the request to /api/sendProofMessage to be sent. But I don't know how to do that. Cause I don't need to wait for the response of that function and that's exactly what the await keyword does.

I places two timestamps into those api routes and measured how much time it takes to send an api request: 1713446472022 − 1713446471979 = 42 (milliseconds). I made 10 tests:

42
3
50
3
4
4
4
3
3
3
So it's pretty fast and 50ms is sufficient.


If deploy on vercel, the delay is increasing drastically: 137, 360, 83, 77, 287. And it's pretty random. Though it still works fine, then I guess to send a request costs less than 50ms.
